# Scraping a web with javascript links

Tags: javascript, r, web, web-scraping

I am using R for web scraping. The information that I need is in the links of [this webpage.](https://www.educacion.gob.es/centros/home.do)
But when I click, the link goes to the same page I was on. How can I scrape the info following these other links until I get the tables with the information I need? I started using R several months ago and I know httr, Curl and other packages, but I am not able to scrape this webpage. I need an output such as this (through clicking "Todo el territorio" and Tipo de estudios: "Bachillerato"):

```
Provincia|Localidad|Denominacion Generica|Denominacion Especifica|Codigo|Naturaleza
Almería|Adra|Instituto de Educación Secundaria|Abdera|04000110|Centro público
Almería|Adra|Instituto de Educación Secundaria|Gaviota|04000134|Centro público
```

...

This would be my general script using Selenium package but it does not work and I accept any option:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(XML)
library(magrittr)

RSelenium::checkForServer()
RSelenium::startServer()
remDrv <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4444, browserName = "chrome")
remDrv$open()

remDrv$navigate('https://www.educacion.gob.es/centros/selectaut.do')
remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath", "//select[@name = '.listado-inicio']/option[@value = ('02','00')]")$clickElement()

...
```

or something like this. I have found something similar to this script looking for other topics in stackoverflow but I do not get anything. I accept other solutions with other scripts.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you show the code you've used so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 'RSelenium' to navigate the site you could do:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
#start RSelenium
checkForServer()
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()

remDr$navigate('https://www.educacion.gob.es/centros/selectaut.do')

#Click on the todo el territorio link
remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//a[text()='Todo el territorio']")$clickElement()

#select the Bachillerato option (has a value of 133) and click on the search button
remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//select[@id='comboniv']/option[@value='133']")$clickElement()
remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//input[@id='idGhost']")$clickElement()

#Click on the show results button
remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//input[@title='Buscar']")$clickElement()

#parse the html and get the table
doc <- htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]],encoding="UTF-8")
data <- readHTMLTable(doc)$matcentro
```

Comment: Now I am trying to follow the links to obtain the info in the following pages for each school (Abdera, Gaviota...) of the data data.frame... (Identificación, ubicación, Tipificación). And I am not able to again. Do you know an easy way to obtain this? Other question. How did you know that 133 is the number for tha "Bachillerato" option? Do you know some manual for these kind of commands using "xpath" and so on? Thanks a lot again.